# IF Statement with multiple conditions and an overriding value

Tags: if-statement

Thanks in advance for helping with this. 
I have an issue where this I need the following formula to calculate this- i would advise seeing the picture in the link to fully understand the question (as I'm probably not going to explain myself!);

**Calculating Risk Score**

Condition 1: If Blood Result is less <=9 or Score <=6 or Tumour Size = <5mm show as text value Low

Condition 2 : If Blood Result 10-20 or Score = 7 or Tumour Size 5mm-9mm show as text value Medium

Condition 3: If Blood Result >=20 or Score = 8 or Tumour Size >=10mm show as text value High

The issue I am having is that any person can have a value from any of the condition, but I need to display the overriding value.

Example:

Blood Result = 5 (condition 1)

Score = 7 (condition 2)

Tumour Size = 10mm (condition 3)

SHOW VALUE: HIGH.

The problemn i'm having is that when I'm doing IF statements, as condition 1 of blood result is True, its always displaying Low without looking at the other values which could overwrite it.

I have only tried nested IF statements with AND OR in them, but no luck.

[See examples of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIEs0.jpg)

Comment: What language? And what have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Check the picture in the link.  I would like to do as forumla, as i don't know programming.  I have tried IF with AND OR functions, but can't get it to work.

Comment: All information must be in the question itself; ideally as text. And if you don't program and haven't tried anything yet, this isn't appropriate for here. We're here to help you with code you've written.

Comment: This the formula i used                              =IF(OR(A5<=9,B5<7,C5="1",C5="2",C5="3",C5="4"),"Low", IF(OR(AND(A5>=10,A5<=19),B5=7,C5="5",C5="6",C5="7",C5="8",C5="9"),"Intermediate"))

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing for that type condition
store your message in one variable, for example, var = msg

```
if condition 1 true assign msg = "Low"
if condition 2 true assign msg = "Medium"
if condition 3 true assign msg = "High"
```

after checking all conditions print your message.

I hope this will help you

Comment: in which language do you want to code.i will explain in that coding format

Comment: I was hoping there was a formula i could put in the cell.  I don't kno how to program

Comment: did you mean excel cell

Comment: yes, i would ideally liek to have a formula i can put in the cell in Excel.

Comment: if you are talking about excel cell . then here are code below:

Comment: =IF(OR(A2<=9,B2<=6,C2<=5),IF(OR(AND(A2>=10,A2<20),B2=7,AND(C2>=5,C2<=9)),IF(OR(A2>=20,B2=8,C2>=10),"High","Medium"),IF(OR(A2>=20,B2=8,C2>=10),"High","Low")))      if you have any Question feel free to contact me and if you have any work you can contact me at Sagarkumar2499@outlook.com i am also a freelancer. thank you